# Magento: which table should be used in the following code?

Tags: magento

I read this article http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-new-custom-category-attribute-in-magento/comment-page-1/

There is part of code in the installer:

```
//this will set data of your custom attribute for root category
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->load(1)
    ->setImportedCatId(0)
    ->setInitialSetupFlag(true)
    ->save();

//this will set data of your custom attribute for default category
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->load(2)
    ->setImportedCatId(0)
    ->setInitialSetupFlag(true)
    ->save();
```

Two question here:

Function load has a parameter. It is ID. *Which table should be used for?*

*What is for setImportedCatId here?* it's setter, but I don't understad what is it for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magento categories still use the EAV table structure, so the table you're interested in is

```
catalog_category_entity
```

However, you won't be able to see the category names here.  Most data for the category objects are persisted to

```
catalog_category_entity_varchar
```

indexed back to the `catalog_category_entity` table by `entity_id`.

I grepped around modern source trees and it appears that the data property  `imported_cat_id` (which is what the setter could be setting), but based on patterns used elsewhere in the Magento system my guess is that some version of Magento has code in the category saving tree that looks for `imported_cat_id`, and if it's set the new category data will be based on the old category.  In other words, it allows you to quickly copy a category and save all it's meta-data.  By setting it to 0 above, the Inchoo code is telling Magento that this is a new category.

That's just a guess though, but it's not something I'd worry about.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find 'imported_cat_id' in whole project at all.